# Maven,GWT and hosted mode

Tags: java, gwt

When I try to run hosted mode with gwt-maven-plugin (`gwt:run`) as [documented](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/hosted.html) on official site 
I'am get an error:

```
The parameters 'runTarget' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:run are missing or invalid
```

How to solve this problem?
**UPDATE:** this is in my POM:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <module>ff.ff.dd.Archiving</module>
                        <runTarget>Archiving.html</runTarget>

                        <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indicate all mandatory configuration options of that [goal](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html).

Comment: yes, I added this configuration to gwt-plugin `<configuration>` section, but it don't help. I updated question and added pice of my pom.xml. thanks

Comment: @MyTitle could you post the whole plugin configuration?

Comment: @MyTitle Move your `<configuration>` block to make it a sibling of `<executions>` block.

Answer (score 0):

In netbean make goal gwt:debug

in properties  -Dgwt.module=UR MODULE NAME -Dgwt.extraJvmArgs=-Xmx2048m -Dgwt.extraJvmArgs=-XX:PermSize=32m -Dgwt.extraJvmArgs=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m war:exploded gwt:debug

and run it now on console u will see the listening port 
now go in Debug menu and select "Attach Debugger"   and just tell port and host .....   now ur GWT Development Mode Start up now u r in GWT Debugging